# Limit of sequence for natural p

Tags: limits

I have to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{1^p + 3^p \dots (2n +1)^p}{n^{p+1}}} = \frac{2^p}{p+1}$ for every $p \in \mathbb{N}$. We have formula $1 + 3 + \dots + (2n +1) = n^2$ but I don't think we can generalize it for $p>1$. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: look at a Riemann sum for $\int_0^2x^pdx$. Play around with it to get only odd $k$ involved in the sum.

Comment: I have to prove it without using integral.

Comment: That seems unreasonable.

Comment: This assignment is exercise for limits of sequence and series.

Comment: Moreover, note that $\int_0^2x^pdx = \frac{x^{p+1}}{p+1} \neq \frac{x^{p}}{p+1}$

Comment: Right, that's what I was talking about with the playing around to get only odd $k$. Your sum is equal to
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\left(\frac{k}n\right)^p\frac1n-2^p\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^p\frac1n.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let
$S_p(n)
=\sum_{k=1}^n k^p
$,
$E_p(n)
=\sum_{k=1}^n (2k)^p
$,
and
$O_p(n)
=\sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)^p
$.

Then
$E_p(n)+O_p(n)
=\sum_{k=1}^n ((2k)^p+(2k-1)^p)
=\sum_{k=1}^{2n} k^p
=S_p(2n)
$.

Therefore
$O_p(n)
=S_p(2n)-E_p(n)
$.

But

$\begin{array}\\
E_p(n)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n (2k)^p\\
&=2^p\sum_{k=1}^n k^p\\
&=2^p S_p(n)
\end{array}
$

so
$O_p(n)
=S_p(2n)-2^p S_p(n)
$.

If you show that
$S_p(n)
\sim\dfrac{n^{p+1}}{p+1}
$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
O_p(n)
&=S_p(2n)-2^p S_p(n)\\
&\sim\dfrac{(2n)^{p+1}}{p+1}-2^p\dfrac{n^{p+1}}{p+1}\\
&=\dfrac{2^{p+1}n^{p+1}-2^pn^{p+1}}{p+1}\\
&=\dfrac{2^{p}n^{p+1}(2-1)}{p+1}\\
&=\dfrac{2^{p}n^{p+1}}{p+1}\\
\end{array}
$

so
$\dfrac{O_p(n)}{n^{p+1}}
\sim \dfrac{2^{p}}{p+1}
$.

It doesn't matter if
you want
$O_p(n)$
or
$O_p(n+1)$
since the last term
is small compared with the sum
(i.e.,
$\dfrac{(2n+1)^p}{n^{p+1}}
\to 0
$).